# Compare two files and replace string in one of them

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for solution to replace one string from one file with string from other file.

Let's say I've two txt files:

**file1**

```
serial_1 serialN1
serial_2 serialN2
```

**file2**

```
something serial_3 serialN1
something serial_4 serialN2
```

What I would like to get is replace `serial_3` with `serial_1`, and `serial_4` with `serial_2`.

So I would like to search `file2` with numbers from second column (serialN) from `file1` and replace "leading" serial number in `file2` when serialN match entry from first file.

What I have so far in PowerShell:

```
$source = Get-Content file1
foreach ($line in $source){
    $position_source = ($line.Split())[1]
    $serial_source = ($line.split())[0]
    $destination = Get-Content file2
    foreach ($destination_line in $destination){
        $position_destination = ($destination_line.Split())[2]
        if ($position_destination -eq $position_source){
            $serial_destination = ($destination_line.Split())[1]
        }
    }
}
```

And this works fine, now I would like to push `$serial_source` in place of `$serial_destination` in `file2`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try something like this

```
$replacementDict = @{}
$sourceLines = Get-Content file1
foreach ($line in $sourceLines) { 
    $parts = $line.Split()
    $position = $parts[1]
    $serial = $parts[0]
    $replacementDict.Add($position, $serial)
}

(Get-Content file2) | 
    % {
        $parts = $_.Split()
        $position = $parts[2]
        if ($replacementDict.($position)) {
            $parts[1] = $replacementDict.$position
        }
        $parts -join ' '
    } | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 file2
```

In your initial code, you read the second file multiple times (once for each line of `file1`) which wastes resources and which probably would also lead to overwriting `file2` multiple times when that would have been implemented.
The code above first creates a dictionary/hash-table from `file1` which maps your 'positions' to serials and then in the second part the contents of `file2` are replaced if their 'position' is found in that dictionary/hash-table. So both files are read only once.

Please note the additional parentheses around `Get-Content file2` which I did to ensure reading the file at once and only after that streaming the contents of it through the pipeline, otherwise it would be possible that `file2` is still open for reading its contents while the end of the pipeline with `Set-Content` already tries to overwrite it.

Last note: the approach above could change your file encoding so you may want to adjust that if necessary.